# Cumulative over table rows with condition Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

**Employees:**

```
employee_id field max_amount
3              a    3000
4              a    3000
1              a    1600
2              a    500
4              b    4000
2              b    4000
3              b    1700
```

ordered by employee, field, amount desc.

**Amounts (pol, premia,field):**

```
pol   premia     field  **assign_to_employee**
11     900        a          3
44     1000       a          3  
55     1400       a          4
77     500        a          3
88     1300       a          1 

22     800        b          4
33     3900       b          2
66     1300       b          4
```

**Assign Stats Table:**

```
employee_id field max_amount true_amount remain
3              a    3000        2400      600
4              a    3000        1400      1600
1              a    1600        1300      300
2              a    500           0       500

4              b    4000        2100      1900
2              b    4000        3900      100
3              b    1700          0       1700
```

The output : assign_to_employee field (merged to amounts table).

**Algoritem wise** : The method is to assign pol's to employees until the premia needs to be added to the cumulative_sum is bigger then the max amount per employee listed in the employees table. You always start with the employess with most max amount until you cannot add any other pols to the employee.

I start with the employees with the grater max_amount per field.

I keep doing this until no pols remains to be assign.

Can you help me solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you attempt something on your own?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.